# Access camera from FileOpenPicker on Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I'm displaying the photos gallery with the following code:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
filePicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

In Windows Phone 8.1 the `FileOpenPicker` is showing the camera button in the `ApplicationBar`.

When using the same code for Windows Phone 10 a confirm and cancel button is shown instead of the camera.

How do I show the camera button as in 8.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapping `Choose location` in the `ApplicationBar` will prompt you with a list of supported apps for photos, including the camera.

Even though I find this less prominent (and weird localisation) than Windows Phone 8.1, I guess this is the way to go to launch the camera.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show the camera button in the application bar in a Windows 10 Mobile app. However, if you do not specify a SuggestedStartLocation, the camera option will be shown upfront in a menu together with other options like files and photos.